# Can't figure out For Loop

Tags: java

I have recently started java, so I unfortunately am terrible at this. I have an question about a for loop question that was asked in my class today, but I can't figure out a part of it.
We were supposed to print out:

```
                           __1__   
                           _333_
                           55555
```

with only for loops.

I have started the code but can't figure out what to do to print out the numbers, though I figured out the spaces.

```
public class Question{
public static void main(String [] args){
    for(int j=1; j<=3;j++){
        for(int i=1; i<=3-j; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
        for(int k=?; k<=?; k??){
        System.out.print(???);
    }
        for(int m=1; m<=3-j; m++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.println();
}
```

The question mark are the place where I don't know what goes in there. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 2; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= (2 * i - 1); k++) {
                System.out.print(i * 2 - 1);
            }
            for (j = 2; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The first for loop will print the `_` before the number, second one will print the number and 3rd one will print the `_` after the number

Answer (score 0):

The values are changing by two each time `j` increments, that leads to the formula `1 + (2 * (j - 1))` which is how you can finish your loops. Like,

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3 - j; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    int n = 1 + (2 * (j - 1));
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    for (int m = 1; m <= 3 - j; m++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs

```
  1  
 333 
55555
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping. I figured out the answer.

```
public class Welcome {
public static void main(String [] args){
    for(int j=1; j<=3;j++){
        for(int i=1; i<=3-j; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
        for(int k=1; k<=(2*j-1); k++){
        System.out.print(2*j-1);
    }
        for(int m=1; m<=3-j; m++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved as below

```
public class ForLoopPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 1;
        int row = 3;
        int column = 5;
        char space = '_';
        for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
                for(int j = 1; j <=column;j++){
                        int offset = (column - number)/2;
                        if( j <= offset ||
                                j > (number + offset)){
                                System.out.print(space);
                        }else{
                                System.out.print(number);
                        }
                }
                System.out.println();
                number += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Here number of For loops are limited to 2 (one for row and one for column).

Logic goes like this -

1. offset provides you number of spaces to be printed at both sides of number.
2. first if condition checks if j (position) is below or above offset and if true it prints underscore and if false it prints number

I know that right answer has been given for this question and it will work like charm. I just tried to optimise code by reducing number of For Loops in answers provided before. Reduction of For loop will improve performance.

Apart from reduction of For loops, this code has following advantage
- This code is more scalable. Just change row, column values (e.g. 5,9) or space char to '*' and check output. You can play with it.

I would suggest you to go with answer given by @Sand to understand For loop and then check this answer to understand how you can optimise it.